# Computed Bootstrap Breakpoints in Nuxt js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, nuxt.js

What is the best solution for having live active Bootstrap breakpoints of screen like a computed data in client side only in a NuxtJs app?

In Bootstrap we have classes like d-lg-block.
I want to do that with v-if in VueJs.
Like:
`<div v-if="lgAndUpper"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need this. This event will be fired once browser being resized. you can put it in `mounted()` to get it work.

```js
window.addEventListener("resize", function(event) {
    console.log(document.body.clientWidth + ' wide by ' + document.body.clientHeight+' high');
})
```